# Is there any interest in a spoiler markdown button?

Tags: feature-request, spoilers, markdown

There is [markdown for spoilers](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/if-you-dont-want-spoilers/187#187): put `>!` at the beginning of a paragraph, and the paragraph will be visible only when the mouse hovers over it, or when it is selected.

> like this

```
!> like this
```

Is there interest in changing one of the markdown buttons above the editing zone? It is technically feasible, but not necessarily a good idea from a user interface point of view as it introduces an inconsistency between SF&F and other Stack Exchange sites.

- Please upvote this question if you'd like the code button to be turned into a spoiler button.
- Please downvote this question if you'd like the code button to remain as it is.
- Please leave a comment or answer if you have a different preference. An extra button is not currently an option.

**Update**: There are currently 17 votes for and 3 against, which I take to mean there is interest.

So: Dear Stack Exchange team, please change the code markup button into a spoiler markup button.

Comment: Perhaps it could at least be mentioned in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help (unless I missed it?). I'm not sure how new SE users are currently meant to find out about it.

Comment: @Tony: [status-requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74999/149076), and in the meantime [please contribute](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74999/so-specific-markup-definitive-resource/79591#79591).

Comment: and others - what's the status of this? Seems like a no-brainer on the need to implement here. We don't need a code button!

Comment: There is a question asking [to update the editing-help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82329/please-update-the-editing-help)

Comment: How about adding this to the FAQ as well?

Answer (score 21):

Yes!  I was recently assaulted by a major spoiler to a series I've been reading.  Anything you can do to make people a little more spoiler-aware would be a positive thing.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate suggestion: What about putting the spoiler markdown in the "How to Format" help pane that appears when focus is in the ask-a-question question text field?

Comment: That's [editing-help](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help) (see Tony's comment above). It's [been requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74999/149076), along with [other undocumented features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74999/so-specific-markup-definitive-resource/79591#79591).

Comment: Okay, neeeevermind. (He said timidly. :)

Comment: Nah, nah, that's good, shows the team there's demand.

Answer (score -7):

I would be against this, simply because it's such a rare need. Not every markdown function is worthy of a button.

Every button and feature we add is another "don't make me think", left unchecked, you can end up with [Homer's Automobile](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/The_Homer).

[image]

Comment: I fail to see why you wouldn't want Homer's Automobile... literally.  I mean it looks pretty rockin'

Comment: If you consider SFF alone, markdown is more useful than code. So by your argument the code button should be removed.

Comment: @gilles ah, REPLACING one button with another is fine. I don't oppose that, except perhaps it breaks consistency between the sites.

Comment: @Jeff, SE used to be all program-ish related (code in SO, scripting, registry, etc in SF & SU). But now, after the great Area 51 r\evolution, the balance is slowly changing. Maybe you ought to break consistency. I can't see how Atheism & Homebrew could benefit from code button.

Comment: We're an sf site, we want a [flying car](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_V7iZ39YZkwM/SdlsqmYRseI/AAAAAAAABcU/61S9mK6Jqdc/s1600-h/SovietFlyingCar.jpg).

Comment: After reading that wiki link, I want the code/spoiler button to play "La Cucaracha" when pressed.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: So, what's the status? planned? declined? six-to-eight-weeks?

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Please respond to Gilles question - this would be a great addition to this site. Please replace the code button with a spoiler button.