# Are there any celebrations planned for us getting out of Beta?

Tags: discussion

This great news should be celebrated *somehow*!

- Are we getting a mention on a StackExchange blog?
- Are our hard working moderators getting a pay rise? (10% seems fair, since they get paid nothing...)?
- Are our top five users going to get a set of Gerry Anderson DVDs?
- Or better yet, are we going to get a [spoiler markdown button](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/432)?

Seriously, this is great news. Thanks to everyone who participated over the last year, going from Area51 through Beta. And thanks to Jin for the awesome graphics!

Comment: Party at my house. Seriously if enough people want to trek over to the Baltimore area.

Comment: @DampeS8N: nice idea. Maybe some kind of Skype / VoIP option would work, with a bring your own beers idea... A distributed party?

Comment: FWIW, the CHAOS team (@BrettWhite) blogged about it (http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/), and Joel tweeted about it (https://twitter.com/#!/spolsky/status/146732377446682624).

Comment: I've noticed that there are **4** users on the first page from Ohio (me and Jeff in Cinci) and 1 from Indiana. Can we get some critical mass for a midwest meetup?

Comment: @gnovice: ditto for [Kepler 22b](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler-22b).

Comment: @DampeS8N - I know I belong on this site since my **main** reaction while reading your first comment was "want to **Star** trek over".

Comment: @Wikis - isn't that what Google+ hangouts are for? I am not quite sure what they are but they seem to be some kinda virtual meetings.

Comment: @DVK: I have no knowledge of this Google+ thing of which you speak... but we have a chat room, of course!

Comment: @TonyMeyer: thanks, that is actually the kind of answer I was expecting. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. Let's formalize it.

If 5+ people say they want to come to my place in the Baltimore MD area for a BYOB party, I'll make it happen. Please include the Saturdays that suit you. Picking Saturday for ease of travel. Limited sofa-bed space available for farthest-distance-traveled-first-serve.

I'll break out the SNES on the 42" next to my Atari 800xl on an SDTV. Continual looping SF films/tv on the giant screen (6' x 8'). Requests welcome.

Right now we are looking at either the 24th or 31st

Comment: If it wasn't ~14000km away...

Comment: I would attend, but sadly the time does not coincide with my next scheduled visit to your planet.

Comment: Baltimore isn't within walking distance or else I'd be over there like white on rice.

Comment: My wife (@spugsley) and I are actually in the Silver Spring area from the 23rd - 1st and could totally do this!

Comment: @DampeS8N go to town.  Might want to consider a Friday night (30th?) as plans for Christmas Eve or New Year's Eve are likely, though less likely in the afternoon.

Comment: @DampeS8N Scrooge! Don't you dare say "humbug"! ;-)

Comment: @IanPugsley Would you still like to get together on the 30th? It'll just be the 4 of us. (you, your wife, me, my girlfriend) Settlers of Catan, maybe?

Comment: Did it happen??

Comment: ...........nope