# Spoiler styling in meta doesn't effectively hide 'spoilers'

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In meta, using `>!` for spoilers gives us:

> text that looks like this!

It's clearly visible.

I know that meta is not really a place where things are likely to be spoiled, but the formatting should probably still work properly so that we can [talk about spoilers](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/432/is-there-any-interest-in-a-spoiler-markdown-button) using correct-looking examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the fix will be in the next daily build.

Comment: woot! (15 chars)

Comment: To clarify for those who didn't notice "Status-completed" tag: this was fixed! Thanks Jin!